# Can you import data from parquet or delta file format data sets into Vertex AI feature store

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai, feature-store

Just wondering if it is possible to not just import from CSV-based data sets for the Vertex AI feature store, but from parquet or delta file formats as well. When trying to import a dataset from within GCP, the only options it gives are from BigQuery or from CSV.

I have attached a picture of the options given

[No Parquet Option - Only CSV and BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHtOv.png)

Does anyone know if there is an API/plug-in/other methodology from which one can load parquet or delta files directly into the Vertex AI feature store?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no.

Vertex AI's Feature Store can only ingest from BigQuery tables or CloudStorage files- the latter of which must be either csv or avro format.

I am not aware of any planned support for Parquet format. However you can load Parquet into BigQuery, so that may be your best option.